# panda datframe plot bar graph tabular format

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I am not sure how to put all these graph in tabular format. All of them are showing up one after another.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 12))
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.5)
for r,x in enumerate(data.county.unique()):
  t_dict={}
  for c,y in enumerate(col):
    if len(data[ (data.county==x) & (data[y]==1)][y].value_counts()) >0 :
     ct=data[ (data.county==x) & (data[y]==1)][y].value_counts().item()
     t_dict.update({y:ct})
  if len(t_dict)>0:
     pd.DataFrame([t_dict]).plot.bar(title=x)
#plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use either [subplots](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html) or [gridspec](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.gridspec.GridSpec.html) to create multiple subplots within a figure and define the number of rows and columns you want to arrange the plots in. As data was not provided, I created a `county` array and an array of `t_tict`s. I have kept the plotting function as is so that you can easily replicate with your data. Hope this is what you are looking for.

```
## Dummy data
county = ['County1', 'County2', 'County3', 'County4', 'County5', 'County6']
t_dict = [{'col1' : 23, 'col2' : 32, 'col3' : 12, 'col4' : 44},
         {'col1' : 13, 'col2' : 30, 'col3' : 32, 'col4' : 4},
         {'col1' : 53, 'col2' : 3, 'col3' : 74, 'col4' : 23},
         {'col1' : 2, 'col2' : 13, 'col3' : 24, 'col4' : 54},
         {'col1' : 3, 'col2' : 32, 'col3' : 52, 'col4' : 21},
         {'col1' : 23, 'col2' : 34, 'col3' : 52, 'col4' : 21},]

## Tell matplotlib that you want 2 rows and 3 columns of plots and axes will define 
## which of the 6 subplots to put the individual plot in
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2,ncols=3,figsize=(15, 12))
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.5)

for i, ax in enumerate(axes.reshape(-1)): ## For each of 6 subplots
    pd.DataFrame([t_dict[i]]).plot.bar(ax=ax, title=county[i])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I did this way. seems working.

```
fig, axs =plt.subplots(8, 5,figsize=(75, 75))
r1=0
c1=0
for r,x in enumerate(data.county.unique()):
  t_dict={}
  for c,y in enumerate(col):
    if len(data[ (data.county==x) & (data[y]==1)][y].value_counts()) >0 :
     ct=data[ (data.county==x) & (data[y]==1)][y].value_counts().item()
     t_dict.update({y:ct})
  if len(t_dict)>0:
    pd.DataFrame([t_dict]).plot.bar(title=x,ax=axs[r1][c1])
    #plt.tight_layout()
    if c1 == 4:
      c1=0
      r1=r1+1
    else:
      c1=c1+1
axs[r1][3].remove()
axs[r1][4].remove()
```